# Отсутствие перевода у заголовка страницы

Tags: дефект, статус-завершено, локализация, отслеживаемые-метки

Имеется [страница](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tab=Frequent&tagMode=Watched) у которой как мне кажется отсутствует перевод заголовка:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

заголовок вкладки в браузере имеется ввиду, а не у самой страницы. [И тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tab=Active&tagMode=Watched) такая же проблема:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[и тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tab=Unanswered&tagMode=Watched):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[и тут](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged?tab=Votes&tagMode=Watched):

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Подравнял и добавил переводы:

> [image: Таблица переводов]

Будет на сайте в новых сборках. Текущая rev 2021.3.18.38835

Comment: Спасибо большое :D